# iOS: How to take snapshot of UIView which has rounded corners?

Tags: ios, uiview

I want to take a snapshot of a UIView as a PNG image. In my case view has rounded corners so, when I take a snapshot it shows the black color where the edges are rounded. I want it to be as transparent. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Here is a code I'm using for getting the image.

```
- (UIImage *)snapshotOfQuoteContainerView {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.outerContainerView.bounds.size, YES, 0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.outerContainerView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return snapshotImage;
}
```

Note: [After changing image size, image's transparent part became black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116857/after-changing-image-size-images-transparent-part-became-black) doesn't address my problem. In my case, it has nothing to do with changing the image size.

Comment: Show. Your. Code.

Comment: And Where is code ?

Comment: source code added.

Comment: show your outerContainerView properties. have you Set "clipsToBound=YES" property  of UIView ?

Comment: Yes, It is set to Yes. I also tried with No. It doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried changing your first call to: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.outerContainerView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);`? The second argument is whether your image should be opaque. And you want transparancy.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` is `opaque`. You provide `YES`, but you need `NO`.

> **opaque**
>
> A Boolean flag indicating whether the bitmap is opaque. If you
>   know the bitmap is fully opaque, specify YES to ignore the alpha
>   channel and optimize the bitmap’s storage. Specifying NO means that
>   the bitmap must include an alpha channel to handle any partially
>   transparent pixels.

Further reading: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623912-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwitho?language=objc